# Creating a second PDF results in an error

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, itext

I am trying to create PDF's using iTextSharp.
When creating the first PDF I don't encounter any problems.
Once I want to create a second PDF file I get the error that there is no access to the file. I think I am not disposing the files correctly.
Below you will find a copy of the PDF generating code.

```
Private Sub GeneratePDF()

    Try



        Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("\\verkoop\offerte v2\Offerte " & offertenummer2 & "-" & offertenummer & " " & TextBox2.Text & ".pdf", FileMode.Create))

        Dim FontColour As BaseColor = New BaseColor(35, 31, 32)
        Dim Calibri8 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 10, FontColour)
        Dim Calibri6 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 6, FontColour)

        Dim img As Image = Image.GetInstance("Resources\Offerte-NL.png")

        MessageBox.Show("Stap2 gelukt")

        Dim ev As New itsEvents
        pdfWrite.PageEvent = ev

        pdfDoc.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Stap3 gelukt")
        'witte lijn

        Dim whiteline As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(" "))
        whiteline.Colspan = 2
        whiteline.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        whiteline.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        'foto inladen

        If RadioButton5.Checked = True Then

            img = Image.GetInstance("Resources\Offerte-NL.png")
            img.ScalePercent(18.0F, 18.0F)
            img.Alignment = 0
            pdfDoc.Add(img)

        ElseIf RadioButton4.Checked = True Then

            img = Image.GetInstance("Resources\Offerte-BE.png")
            img.ScalePercent(18.0F, 18.0F)
            img.Alignment = 0
            pdfDoc.Add(img)

        End If


        'Eerste table in PDF voor klantgegevens

        Dim klanttable As New PdfPTable(2)
        klanttable.TotalWidth = 350.0F
        klanttable.LockedWidth = True
        klanttable.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        'klanttable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        Dim sglTblHdWidths(1) As Single
        sglTblHdWidths(0) = 120
        sglTblHdWidths(1) = 230
        klanttable.SetWidths(sglTblHdWidths)

        Dim kollommatenproduct(5) As Single
        kollommatenproduct(0) = 45
        kollommatenproduct(1) = 45
        kollommatenproduct(2) = 200
        kollommatenproduct(3) = 65
        kollommatenproduct(4) = 60
        kollommatenproduct(5) = 55


        klanttable.SetWidths(sglTblHdWidths)




        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Debiteur gegevens"))

        cell.Colspan = 2
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        Dim debnr As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim bn As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim adr As String = TextBox3.Text
        Dim pcwp As String = TextBox4.Text
        Dim cp As String = TextBox5.Text
        Dim km As String = TextBox6.Text

        klanttable.AddCell(cell)
        klanttable.AddCell(whiteline)
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("Debiteur nr.: ", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(debnr, Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("(Bedrijfs)naam:", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(bn, Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("Adres:", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(adr, Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("Postcode & woonplaats:", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(pcwp, Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("Contactpersoon", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(cp, Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("Kenmerk:", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(km, Calibri8))
        klanttable.SpacingBefore = 50.0F
        klanttable.SpacingAfter = 75.0F


        pdfDoc.Add(klanttable)

        'Offerte nummer tabel

        Dim offerteinfotable As New PdfPTable(2)
        offerteinfotable.TotalWidth = 350.0F
        offerteinfotable.LockedWidth = True
        offerteinfotable.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        'offerteinfotable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        offerteinfotable.SetWidths(sglTblHdWidths)


        Dim cell2 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Offerte informatie"))
        cell2.Colspan = 2
        cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        cell2.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        offerteinfotable.AddCell(cell2)
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(whiteline)
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Offertenummer:", Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(offertenummer2.ToString + "-" + offertenummer.ToString, Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Datum:", Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString, Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Contactpersoon:", Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(Login.TextBox3.Text.ToString, Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.SpacingAfter = 75.0F

        pdfDoc.Add(offerteinfotable)


        'Extra informatie offerte

        Dim offerteextrainfotable As New PdfPTable(2)
        offerteextrainfotable.TotalWidth = 350.0F
        offerteextrainfotable.LockedWidth = True
        offerteextrainfotable.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        'offerteinfotable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        offerteextrainfotable.SetWidths(sglTblHdWidths)


        Dim cell3 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Leverings informatie"))
        cell3.Colspan = 2
        cell3.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        cell3.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(cell3)
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(whiteline)
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Betalingscondities:", Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(ComboBox3.Text.ToString, Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Levertermijn:", Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(ComboBox4.Text.ToString, Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Extra informatie:", Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(TextBox7.Text.ToString, Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.SpacingAfter = 150.0F

        pdfDoc.Add(offerteextrainfotable)

        'pagina 2
        pdfDoc.NewPage()

        'Header invoegen

        pdfDoc.Add(img)

        'producten invoegen

        Dim productentable As New PdfPTable(6)
        productentable.TotalWidth = 530.0F
        productentable.LockedWidth = True
        productentable.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        productentable.DefaultCell.PaddingBottom = 5
        productentable.DefaultCell.PaddingTop = 5


        productentable.SetWidths(kollommatenproduct)

        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Aantal", Calibri8))
        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Art. Nr.", Calibri8))
        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Omschrijving", Calibri8))
        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Capaciteit", Calibri8))
        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Prijs per stuk", Calibri8))
        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Prijs totaal", Calibri8))

        Dim totaalincbtw As Decimal = 0.00
        Dim totaalexbtw As Decimal = 0.00


        For Each Row In DataGridView1.Rows

            If Not Row.IsNewRow Then

                Dim aantal As String = Row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
                Dim artikelnummer As String = Row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
                Dim omschrijving As String = Row.Cells(5).Value.ToString
                Dim capaciteit As String = Row.Cells(2).Value.ToString + Row.Cells(3).Value.ToString
                Dim prijsperstukinc As Decimal = Row.Cells(4).Value.ToString
                Dim prijsperstuk As Decimal = Math.Round(prijsperstukinc / 1.21, 2)
                Dim tot1 As Decimal = Row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
                Dim tot2 As Decimal = Row.Cells(4).Value.ToString
                Dim totaalprijsex As Decimal = Math.Round(tot1 * tot2 / 1.21, 2)
                Dim totaalprijsinc As Decimal = Math.Round(tot1 * tot2, 2)

                totaalincbtw = totaalincbtw + totaalprijsinc
                totaalexbtw = totaalexbtw + totaalprijsex

                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase(aantal, Calibri8))
                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase(artikelnummer, Calibri8))
                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase(omschrijving, Calibri8))
                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase(capaciteit, Calibri8))
                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("€ " + prijsperstuk.ToString, Calibri8))
                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("€ " + totaalprijsex.ToString, Calibri8))

            End If

        Next


        'totaal bedragen toevoegen

        Dim btw As Decimal = totaalincbtw - totaalexbtw

        Dim blankcell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(" "))
        blankcell.Colspan = 3
        blankcell.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        blankcell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        Dim subtotaalcell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Subtotaal:", Calibri8))
        subtotaalcell.UseVariableBorders = True
        subtotaalcell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER + Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER


        Dim btw21cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("BTW 21%", Calibri8))
        btw21cell.UseVariableBorders = True
        btw21cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER + Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER



        Dim totaalbedragcell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Totaalbedrag:", Calibri8))
        totaalbedragcell.UseVariableBorders = True
        totaalbedragcell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER + Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER



        Dim tussencel As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(" ", Calibri8))
        tussencel.UseVariableBorders = True
        tussencel.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER
        tussencel.PaddingBottom = 5



        Dim subtotaalcell2 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("€ " + totaalexbtw.ToString, Calibri8))
        subtotaalcell2.UseVariableBorders = True
        subtotaalcell2.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER



        Dim btw21cell2 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("€ " + btw.ToString, Calibri8))
        btw21cell2.UseVariableBorders = True
        btw21cell2.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER



        Dim totaalbedragcell2 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("€ " + totaalincbtw.ToString, Calibri8))
        totaalbedragcell2.UseVariableBorders = True
        totaalbedragcell2.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER



        productentable.AddCell(blankcell)
        productentable.AddCell(blankcell)

        productentable.AddCell(blankcell)
        productentable.AddCell(subtotaalcell)
        productentable.AddCell(tussencel)
        productentable.AddCell(subtotaalcell2)


        productentable.AddCell(blankcell)
        productentable.AddCell(btw21cell)
        productentable.AddCell(tussencel)
        productentable.AddCell(btw21cell2)

        productentable.AddCell(blankcell)
        productentable.AddCell(totaalbedragcell)
        productentable.AddCell(tussencel)
        productentable.AddCell(totaalbedragcell2)



        pdfDoc.Add(productentable)


        pdfDoc.Close()
        pdfDoc.Dispose()

        pdfWrite.Dispose()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())

    End Try

End Sub
```

When cathing the error I get the following message.

[image: error]

This error marks line 602 and that is the line with this part of code "pdfDoc.Open()"

I am guessing that somehow something isn't disposed properly.

If anyone has an idea that would be great :D

Edit:

Forgot to mention I have this line my class

```
Shared pdfDoc As New Document()
```

Edit2: Solution !

I just moved the line   Shared pdfDoc As New Document()
To my Private sub GeneratePDF before

```
Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("\\verkoop\offerte v2\Offerte " & offertenummer2 & "-" & offertenummer & " " & TextBox2.Text & ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
```

Current code is working and looks like this:

```
 Private Sub GeneratePDF()

    Try

        Dim pdfDoc As New Document()

        Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("\\verkoop\offerte v2\Offerte " & offertenummer2 & "-" & offertenummer & " " & TextBox2.Text & ".pdf", FileMode.Create))

        Dim FontColour As BaseColor = New BaseColor(35, 31, 32)
        Dim Calibri8 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 10, FontColour)
        Dim Calibri6 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 6, FontColour)

        Dim img As Image = Image.GetInstance("Resources\Offerte-NL.png")

        MessageBox.Show("Stap2 gelukt")

        Dim ev As New itsEvents
        pdfWrite.PageEvent = ev

        pdfDoc.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Stap3 gelukt")
        'witte lijn

        Dim whiteline As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(" "))
        whiteline.Colspan = 2
        whiteline.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        whiteline.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        'foto inladen

        If RadioButton5.Checked = True Then

            img = Image.GetInstance("Resources\Offerte-NL.png")
            img.ScalePercent(18.0F, 18.0F)
            img.Alignment = 0
            pdfDoc.Add(img)

        ElseIf RadioButton4.Checked = True Then

            img = Image.GetInstance("Resources\Offerte-BE.png")
            img.ScalePercent(18.0F, 18.0F)
            img.Alignment = 0
            pdfDoc.Add(img)

        End If


        'Eerste table in PDF voor klantgegevens

        Dim klanttable As New PdfPTable(2)
        klanttable.TotalWidth = 350.0F
        klanttable.LockedWidth = True
        klanttable.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        'klanttable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        Dim sglTblHdWidths(1) As Single
        sglTblHdWidths(0) = 120
        sglTblHdWidths(1) = 230
        klanttable.SetWidths(sglTblHdWidths)

        Dim kollommatenproduct(5) As Single
        kollommatenproduct(0) = 45
        kollommatenproduct(1) = 45
        kollommatenproduct(2) = 200
        kollommatenproduct(3) = 65
        kollommatenproduct(4) = 60
        kollommatenproduct(5) = 55


        klanttable.SetWidths(sglTblHdWidths)




        Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Debiteur gegevens"))

        cell.Colspan = 2
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        Dim debnr As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim bn As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim adr As String = TextBox3.Text
        Dim pcwp As String = TextBox4.Text
        Dim cp As String = TextBox5.Text
        Dim km As String = TextBox6.Text

        klanttable.AddCell(cell)
        klanttable.AddCell(whiteline)
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("Debiteur nr.: ", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(debnr, Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("(Bedrijfs)naam:", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(bn, Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("Adres:", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(adr, Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("Postcode & woonplaats:", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(pcwp, Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("Contactpersoon", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(cp, Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase("Kenmerk:", Calibri8))
        klanttable.AddCell(New Phrase(km, Calibri8))
        klanttable.SpacingBefore = 50.0F
        klanttable.SpacingAfter = 75.0F


        pdfDoc.Add(klanttable)

        'Offerte nummer tabel

        Dim offerteinfotable As New PdfPTable(2)
        offerteinfotable.TotalWidth = 350.0F
        offerteinfotable.LockedWidth = True
        offerteinfotable.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        'offerteinfotable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        offerteinfotable.SetWidths(sglTblHdWidths)


        Dim cell2 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Offerte informatie"))
        cell2.Colspan = 2
        cell2.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        cell2.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        offerteinfotable.AddCell(cell2)
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(whiteline)
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Offertenummer:", Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(offertenummer2.ToString + "-" + offertenummer.ToString, Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Datum:", Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString, Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Contactpersoon:", Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(Login.TextBox3.Text.ToString, Calibri8))
        offerteinfotable.SpacingAfter = 75.0F

        pdfDoc.Add(offerteinfotable)


        'Extra informatie offerte

        Dim offerteextrainfotable As New PdfPTable(2)
        offerteextrainfotable.TotalWidth = 350.0F
        offerteextrainfotable.LockedWidth = True
        offerteextrainfotable.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        'offerteinfotable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        offerteextrainfotable.SetWidths(sglTblHdWidths)


        Dim cell3 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Leverings informatie"))
        cell3.Colspan = 2
        cell3.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        cell3.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(cell3)
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(whiteline)
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Betalingscondities:", Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(ComboBox3.Text.ToString, Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Levertermijn:", Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(ComboBox4.Text.ToString, Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase("Extra informatie:", Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.AddCell(New Phrase(TextBox7.Text.ToString, Calibri8))
        offerteextrainfotable.SpacingAfter = 150.0F

        pdfDoc.Add(offerteextrainfotable)

        'pagina 2
        pdfDoc.NewPage()

        'Header invoegen

        pdfDoc.Add(img)

        'producten invoegen

        Dim productentable As New PdfPTable(6)
        productentable.TotalWidth = 530.0F
        productentable.LockedWidth = True
        productentable.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        productentable.DefaultCell.PaddingBottom = 5
        productentable.DefaultCell.PaddingTop = 5


        productentable.SetWidths(kollommatenproduct)

        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Aantal", Calibri8))
        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Art. Nr.", Calibri8))
        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Omschrijving", Calibri8))
        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Capaciteit", Calibri8))
        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Prijs per stuk", Calibri8))
        productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("Prijs totaal", Calibri8))

        Dim totaalincbtw As Decimal = 0.00
        Dim totaalexbtw As Decimal = 0.00


        For Each Row In DataGridView1.Rows

            If Not Row.IsNewRow Then

                Dim aantal As String = Row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
                Dim artikelnummer As String = Row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
                Dim omschrijving As String = Row.Cells(5).Value.ToString
                Dim capaciteit As String = Row.Cells(2).Value.ToString + Row.Cells(3).Value.ToString
                Dim prijsperstukinc As Decimal = Row.Cells(4).Value.ToString
                Dim prijsperstuk As Decimal = Math.Round(prijsperstukinc / 1.21, 2)
                Dim tot1 As Decimal = Row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
                Dim tot2 As Decimal = Row.Cells(4).Value.ToString
                Dim totaalprijsex As Decimal = Math.Round(tot1 * tot2 / 1.21, 2)
                Dim totaalprijsinc As Decimal = Math.Round(tot1 * tot2, 2)

                totaalincbtw = totaalincbtw + totaalprijsinc
                totaalexbtw = totaalexbtw + totaalprijsex

                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase(aantal, Calibri8))
                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase(artikelnummer, Calibri8))
                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase(omschrijving, Calibri8))
                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase(capaciteit, Calibri8))
                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("€ " + prijsperstuk.ToString, Calibri8))
                productentable.AddCell(New Phrase("€ " + totaalprijsex.ToString, Calibri8))

            End If

        Next


        'totaal bedragen toevoegen

        Dim btw As Decimal = totaalincbtw - totaalexbtw

        Dim blankcell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(" "))
        blankcell.Colspan = 3
        blankcell.HorizontalAlignment = 0
        blankcell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER

        Dim subtotaalcell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Subtotaal:", Calibri8))
        subtotaalcell.UseVariableBorders = True
        subtotaalcell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER + Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER


        Dim btw21cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("BTW 21%", Calibri8))
        btw21cell.UseVariableBorders = True
        btw21cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER + Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER



        Dim totaalbedragcell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Totaalbedrag:", Calibri8))
        totaalbedragcell.UseVariableBorders = True
        totaalbedragcell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER + Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER



        Dim tussencel As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(" ", Calibri8))
        tussencel.UseVariableBorders = True
        tussencel.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER
        tussencel.PaddingBottom = 5



        Dim subtotaalcell2 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("€ " + totaalexbtw.ToString, Calibri8))
        subtotaalcell2.UseVariableBorders = True
        subtotaalcell2.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER



        Dim btw21cell2 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("€ " + btw.ToString, Calibri8))
        btw21cell2.UseVariableBorders = True
        btw21cell2.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER



        Dim totaalbedragcell2 As New PdfPCell(New Phrase("€ " + totaalincbtw.ToString, Calibri8))
        totaalbedragcell2.UseVariableBorders = True
        totaalbedragcell2.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER + Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER + Rectangle.TOP_BORDER



        productentable.AddCell(blankcell)
        productentable.AddCell(blankcell)

        productentable.AddCell(blankcell)
        productentable.AddCell(subtotaalcell)
        productentable.AddCell(tussencel)
        productentable.AddCell(subtotaalcell2)


        productentable.AddCell(blankcell)
        productentable.AddCell(btw21cell)
        productentable.AddCell(tussencel)
        productentable.AddCell(btw21cell2)

        productentable.AddCell(blankcell)
        productentable.AddCell(totaalbedragcell)
        productentable.AddCell(tussencel)
        productentable.AddCell(totaalbedragcell2)



        pdfDoc.Add(productentable)


        pdfDoc.Close()
        pdfDoc.Dispose()

        pdfWrite.Dispose()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())

    End Try

End Sub
```

Thank you for the help !!! :D

Comment: Is your pdfDoc a global variable?
I would create a new instance of pdfDoc every time that your sub is called upon.

Comment: I don't see you creating the `pdfDoc` object. It seems that you're only using one instance to create multiple PDF's. That causes the exception you encounter. You should create a new `Document` instance for every separate document.

Comment: Sorry forgot to post that I had  

Shared pdfDoc As New Document()

In my class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you don't create a new instance of it in your code, you appear to re-use the `Document pdfDoc` object. That cannot work, iText `Document` objects are one-shot only.

Thus, add

```
pdfDoc = New Document
```

before

```
Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("\\verkoop\offerte v2\Offerte " & offertenummer2 & "-" & offertenummer & " " & TextBox2.Text & ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, had it placed in the wrong spot.